# Manually calculating $SS_W$ for a one way ANOVA

Tags: anova, sums-of-squares

Question Details:

group 1:
$n = 30$,
$M = 78$,
$SD = 8$

group 2:
$n = 30$,
$M = 70$,
$SD = 13$

group 3:
$n = 30$,
$M = 64$,
$SD = 13$

I have to manually calculate a one way ANOVA summary table. 
I have been able to work out $SS_B$ (690.634)
I have attempted to calculate $SS_W$ by squaring each $SD$ to find the variance then multiplying each variance by $n-1$ before summing the 3 scores, though the number seems really large and I'm not sure if I'm completely off track.

Any guidance would be very much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

$$
\overline{x} = \frac{\displaystyle \sum_{i = 1}^k n_i \overline{x}_i }{n} = \frac{30 \cdot 78 + 30 \cdot 70 + 30 \cdot 64}{90} \approx 70.6667
$$

$$
SS_B = \sum_{i = 1}^k n_i \left( \overline{x}_i - \overline{x} \right)^2 = 30 \cdot \left( 78 - 70.6667 \right)^2 + 30 \cdot \left( 70 - 70.6667 \right)^2 + 30 \cdot \left( 64 - 70.6667 \right)^2 = 2960
$$

$$
SS_W = \sum_{i = 1}^k \left( n_i - 1 \right) s_i^2 = 29 \cdot 8^2 + 29 \cdot 13^2 + 29 \cdot 13^2 = 11658
$$

(assumed the SDs are the estimated standard deviations ($s_i$) of the groups, not the real/theoretical/population ones ($\sigma_i$))

$$
F = \frac{MS_B}{MS_W} = \frac{\displaystyle \frac{SS_B}{k - 1}}{\displaystyle \frac{SS_W}{n - k}} = \frac{\displaystyle \frac{2960}{2}}{\displaystyle \frac{11658}{87}} \approx 11.0448
$$

R code for the calculations:

```
n.i <- c(30, 30, 30)
m.i <- c(78, 70, 64)
s.i <- c(8, 13, 13)

k <- length(n.i)
n <- sum(n.i)
m <- sum(n.i * m.i) / n

SS.B <- sum(n.i * (m.i - m)^2)
SS.W <- sum((n.i - 1) * s.i^2)
F <- (SS.B / (k - 1)) / (SS.W / (n - k))
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the SS within will be quite large.  However, the DoF within will be fairly large as well, 87 I believe for this case.  And you divide that SS within by the DoF within before dividing the SS between (also scaled by its smaller DoF) by it.